# How to convert string from variable in table for csv-export?

Tags: python

I am an absolute beginner with Python (the title probably says it already).I usually look for the answers with googling, but here I don't even know what term to look for....  I have a long string in a variable, which I suppose will be easily converted to a table, only I can't figure out how to do it myself

This is my example:

```
#pip install pycoingecko
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
output = cg.get_search_trending()
print(output)
```

This is the output:

```
{'coins': [{'item': {'id': 'metavpad', 'coin_id': 21397, 'name': 'MetaVPad', 'symbol': 'METAV', 'market_cap_rank': 511, 'thumb': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/21397/thumb/metav.png?1639044315', 'small': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/21397/small/metav.png?1639044315', 'large': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/21397/large/metav.png?1639044315', 'slug': 'metavpad', 'price_btc': 7.777707600278187e-06, 'score': 0}}, {'item': {'id': 'syscoin', 'coin_id': 119, 'name': 'Syscoin', 'symbol': 'SYS', 'market_cap_rank': 189, 'thumb': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/119/thumb/Syscoin.png?1560401261', 'small': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/119/small/Syscoin.png?1560401261', 'large': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/119/large/Syscoin.png?1560401261', 'slug': 'syscoin', 'price_btc': 1.3905286168359925e-05, 'score': 1}}, {'item': {'id': 'rainbowtoken', 'coin_id': 17828, 'name': 'RainbowToken', 'symbol': 'RAINBOWTOKEN', 'market_cap_rank': 907, 'thumb': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/17828/thumb/WsLiOeJ.png?1637337787', 'small': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/17828/small/WsLiOeJ.png?1637337787', 'large': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/17828/large/WsLiOeJ.png?1637337787', 'slug': 'rainbowtoken', 'price_btc': 5.831112758941096e-13, 'score': 2}}, {'item': {'id': 'railgun', 'coin_id': 16840, 'name': 'Railgun', 'symbol': 'RAIL', 'market_cap_rank': 534, 'thumb': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/16840/thumb/railgun.jpeg?1625322775', 'small': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/16840/small/railgun.jpeg?1625322775', 'large': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/16840/large/railgun.jpeg?1625322775', 'slug': 'railgun', 'price_btc': 3.1094468809624446e-05, 'score': 3}}, {'item': {'id': 'wonderland', 'coin_id': 18126, 'name': 'Wonderland', 'symbol': 'TIME', 'market_cap_rank': 113, 'thumb': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/18126/thumb/time.PNG?1630621941', 'small': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/18126/small/time.PNG?1630621941', 'large': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/18126/large/time.PNG?1630621941', 'slug': 'wonderland', 'price_btc': 0.08713452772286424, 'score': 4}}, {'item': {'id': 'gods-unchained', 'coin_id': 17139, 'name': 'Gods Unchained', 'symbol': 'GODS', 'market_cap_rank': 274, 'thumb': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/17139/thumb/10631.png?1635718182', 'small': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/17139/small/10631.png?1635718182', 'large': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/17139/large/10631.png?1635718182', 'slug': 'gods-unchained', 'price_btc': 0.00014524078849750436, 'score': 5}}, {'item': {'id': 'altura', 
'coin_id': 15127, 'name': 'Altura', 'symbol': 'ALU', 'market_cap_rank': 456, 'thumb': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/15127/thumb/ALU_logo_200x200.png?1626868890', 'small': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/15127/small/ALU_logo_200x200.png?1626868890', 'large': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/15127/large/ALU_logo_200x200.png?1626868890', 'slug': 'altura', 'price_btc': 3.302478861283615e-06, 'score': 6}}], 'exchanges': []}
```

Now how can I convert this to export it to a CSV? Or what keywords do I have to search for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, to put everything in `'coins'` to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
output = cg.get_search_trending()

tab = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in output['coins']],axis=1).T
tab.index = range(tab.shape[0])
```

The data frame looks like this:

```
  coin_id              id  ...        symbol                                              thumb
0   21397        metavpad  ...         METAV  https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/2139...
1     119         syscoin  ...           SYS  https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/119/...
2   17828    rainbowtoken  ...  RAINBOWTOKEN  https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1782...
3   16840         railgun  ...          RAIL  https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1684...
4   10354          insure  ...          SURE  https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1035...
5   18126      wonderland  ...          TIME  https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1812...
6   17139  gods-unchained  ...          GODS  https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1713...
```

You can write it to a csv:

```
tab.to_csv("results.csv")
```